# Saving nested subdocument with schema of parent type with Mongoose and expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to nest documents in Mongoose with the same type of the parent Schema. The `return res.json(forum);` will return exactly how I want it to save in the database but the mongoose model won't save past a depth of 1 subdocument, then those subdocuments won't save any subdocuments they were assigned

I've tried to change the type of the Subdocument to simply a type of Object however they still won't be saved and that also isn't desirable as they won't be given an ObjectId

The code I have at the moment looks like this

```
const Forum = require('../model/forum.model');

router.post('/api/create/topic', (req, res, next) => {
  Forum.find()
    .then((forum) => {

      const topic = new Forum({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        groups: req.body.groups || ['public'],
        deleted: false,
        url: `${req.body.title.replace(/ /g,"-").toLowerCase()}`,
      });

      function findParentForum(parent) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(parent) !== '[object Array]')
          parent = [parent];
        for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
          if (parent[i]['_id'] == req.body._id) {
            parent[i].topics.push(topic);
            break;
          } else {
            if (parent[i].topics.length > 0) {
              findParentForum(parent[i].topics);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      findParentForum(forum);

      forum.forEach((forum, index) => {
        forum.save().then(() => {}).catch((err) => { return next(err); });
      });

      return res.json(forum);

    }).catch((err) => {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

The Schema I have defined is below

```
const ForumSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  topics: [this],
  deleted: Boolean,
  groups: [],
  owners: [],
  url: String,
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Forum', ForumSchema);
```

Success for what I have in mind would be an unlimited amount of subdocuments within subdocuments like what is currently being returned by the `return res.json(forum);`

Example

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  title: "parent",
  topics: [{
    _id: "4321",
    title: "child",
    topics: [{
      _id: "5678",
      title: "subchild",
      topics: []
    },
    {
    _id: "999",
    title: "another child",
    topics: [],
  }],
}
```

I appreciate any answers or recommendations, thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution? please share

Comment: @nitin.agam I never did, sorry man

Comment: No worries, my issue has been resolved !!